# stuck in git rebase and ignored/removed files wont remain ignored

Tags: git, rebase, gitignore

Ok first issue:
  I'm not entirely sure how as im rather new to git but I am now stuck with the branch `master:REBASE`. **EDIT** I was using github's windows client to pull down some changes i had pushed from another pc. Git error-ed saying I had unstaged files and could not complete. I don't have the exact message because I closed the window on accident. I have no idea how to get through this.

Second issue is with untracking files O have `git rm --cached <filename>` literally 5 times and these three file just keep coming back. I have made sure to add the entire directory to my .gitignore and these are the only three i have problems with.

**EDIT**
.gitignore contents

```
#################  
## Eclipse
#################

    *.pydevproject
    .project
    .metadata
    bin/
    tmp/
    *.tmp
    *.bak
    *.swp
    *~.nib
    local.properties
    .classpath
    .settings/
    .loadpath

    # External tool builders
    .externalToolBuilders/

    # Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
    *.launch

    # CDT-specific
    .cproject

    # PDT-specific
    .buildpath


############
## Windows 
############

    # Windows image file caches
    Thumbs.db

    # Folder config file
    Desktop.ini

#########
#archives
#########
    *.zip

##############
#OOE Specifics
##############
#Generated files and directories
/txt
/signed 
/unsigned
/hi7
logindetails.csv
/timer/
config.php
```

example of file to be ignored/removed:

```
timer/jquery.timeentry-zh-CN.js  
timer/jquery.timeentry-pl.js  
timer/jquery.timeentry-ru.js
timer/jquery.timeentry-hu.js
```

also i want to keep these files in the working directory i just dont want to have them being tracked.

If any more info or clarification is needed please let me know.

Comment: This question definitely needs more context. What were you trying to do before you got stuck? What did you **actually** do? Which files are you trying to remove/ignore, and what are the contents of your .gitignore?

Comment: `git rebase --abort` should clean up after a failed rebase, putting you back to where you were before the rebase. For the non-ignored files - were they actually tracked at some point in the past (or are they tracked now) despite them possibly matching something in `.gitignore`? Adding tracked files to `.gitignore` can lead to some confusion, and if the tracked/ignored status of those files changed at some point during the rebase range you're working with, that could be confusing things...

Comment: @twalberg doesn't `git rm --cached timer/* -r` remove that tracking?

Comment: @Bill.Caffery Not until a `git commit` stores those changes.

Comment: @Bill.Caffery It removes them from the index, but if you do a `git checkout` or anything else that moves to a different commit without actually committing those changes, the effects of `git rm --cached` could be lost... (For some reason, SO wouldn't let me edit previous comment to add this...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rm -cached <file>` didn't work so I made sure the `.gitignore` was correct and removed the timer dir from the repo. Commited the changes and push to github. Then I put timer back and the directory was ignored.

As for the rebase issue, @twalberg was correct `git rebase --abort` was just what i needed.

I then reverted to the last correct commit and voila.